# GTK Icons for special files

Tags: gnome, gtk, theme, icons

Does named pipe for instance have it's icon, I have a theme for GTK and when I've create named pipe it give icon from `gtk-file.svg` file or symlinks that point to that:

- application-x-empty.svg
- empty.svg
- gnome-fs-regular.svg

Is there a place where I can find a list of those types? I can't find them in `/usr/share/mime`.

I found this 2 links:

- https://developer.gnome.org/icon-naming-spec/
- http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html

but there is no `gnome-fs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does have an icon name: `inode-fifo`. The icon name usually matches the mime type, in this case `inode/fifo`.
And yes, you cannot find it in the official docs because the specification does not list all possible icon names it only aims to (emphasize mine):

```
lay out a standard naming scheme for icon creation, as well as providing 
a minimal list of must have icons.
```

The easy way to determine the icon name for a particular mime type is via `gio`:

```
gio info -a standard::icon LOCATION
```

(on older setups replace `gio info` with `gvfs-info`)

```
mkfifo namedpipe
gvfs-info -a standard::icon namedpipe
uri: file:///home/don/testdir/namedpipe
attributes:
  standard::icon: inode-fifo, inode-x-generic
```

So the standard icon name is `inode-fifo` and the generic name is `inode-x-generic`. If `inode-fifo.png` is missing from your icon set then `inode-x-generic.png` will be used. If that one is missing too, a fallback icon name will be used, e.g. `gnome-fs-regular.png`.