# different icons for generic source-code and other files

Tags: gnome3, icons

I am trying to make a mimetype icon theme for gnome.
I have created `text-x-generic.svg` for all unthemed filetype.
But what I am looking for is different icons for unthemed source code (say, R, vala,awk etc) and plain-generic text file.

Is this possible?

**N.B.** I have tried `text-x-generic.svg` and `text-generic.svg` to differentiate the source code and plain text, but that is not what linux(gnome) understands.

**reply for don_crissti's Comment** Say, I have icons for `ruby`, and `js`, but not for `C` and `R`. So, `file.c` and `file.r` should show the icons for `text-x-generic-unthemed-sourcecode` icon.
And `file.dat` and `filename_without_extensions` should show a different icons (`text-generic-plaintext`).

File-wise, they are different, as

```
$ file i.c
i.c: C source, ASCII text

$ file dos.dat
dos.dat: ASCII text
```

So, there should be some way.

Comment: Gnome cares about the [shared MIME-info database](https://developer.gnome.org/shared-mime-info-spec/), not about `file(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @don_crissti for the details of how it works.
I have gone an alternate way for solving the problem partially.
I have put different icons for `text-plain` and `text-x-generic` and `text-x-script`. 
The `text-plain` incorporates all the files without extensions and like of .dat, .txt etc; where `text-x-[generic,script]` is the fallback for others and scripts.

I agree this is an ad-hoc solution, but it solves the current problem nonetheless. (The best solution is to make icons for each files in `/usr/share/mime/*`)

A screenshot is added to show how it looks with only `text-x-[python,xml,scripts,generic,plain]`

[image: A screenshot is added]

Comment: (or) you can place the icon under `~/.local/share/icons/` aswell if you dont want this icon to be available only for current user, not all users.

In my case for mime-type `application/vnd.jgraph.mxfile`, I placed a file under `~/.local/share/icons/application-vnd.jgraph.mxfile.png`

Answer (score 4):

The icons used by `gnome` are based on mime type hence your `file.c` will not be detected as `text-x-generic-unthemed` but as `text-x-csrc` and since you have no associated icon it will fallback to `text-x-generic`.
Ex: the icons used for `.vala` are: `text-x-vala, text-x-generic` but since there is no `text-x-vala` icon in my icon set, the system falls back to `text-x-generic`:

[image]

See the post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123018) on how to determine the associated icons for a specific mime type.

---

In order to use a different fallback icon (e.g. `text-x-unthemed`) one has to customize definitions for mime types that should fall back to this particular icon and add the relevant icon (`text-x-unthemed`) to the icon set under `mimetypes` .

1. Add the icon, then update the icon cache:

   ```
   gtk-update-icon-cache /path/to/icon_theme_directory
   ```
2. Add custom definitions for mime types that should use `text-x-unthemed` as generic (fallback) icon if they have no corresponding icons.
   Create `unthemed.xml` file under `~/.local/share/mime/packages` e.g.:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
     <mime-type type="text/x-vala">
       <comment>Vala source code</comment>
       <glob pattern="*.vala" case-sensitive="true"/>
       <generic-icon name="text-x-unthemed"/>
     </mime-type>
    </mime-info>
   ```

   Add other mime types to the list if needed (use *vala* `<mime-type>` block as a template).
3. Rebuild the mime cache with:

   ```
   update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
   ```

The system should then fall back to `text-x-unthemed` icon for `.vala` files:

[image]

If a dedicated icon `text-x-vala` is added later on, the system will use that one, e.g.:

[image]

---

Don't forget to update the icon and mime cache each time you add/remove icons or mime type definitions.