# Configure nautilus icon for new mime type

Tags: nautilus, icons, mime-types

How does `nautilus` find the icon for a given mimetype? I have just registered a [new mimetype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134239/how-to-register-a-shell-script-as-the-main-application-for-a-given-file-extensio) for Umlet on my system.

Additionally I added an icon with using:

```
xdg-icon-resource install --novendor --context mimetypes \
                          --size 64 umlet_logo.png umlet
```

Then I added `Icon=` to the `.desktop` file, which I registered for my mime type. Now `nautilus` shows the icon in the context menu together with the name of the default application for that mime type.

However the icon of the file itself still shows some generic `text`-type icon like for normal text files. I would like to change the icon type of my application to this new mime-type.

I found some [guides](https://coderwall.com/p/qjda2q/create-new-mime-type-and-assign-an-icon-to-it-in-ubuntu), but they assume I have a svg file and ask me to copy the `.svg` into some `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable` followed by calling `gtk-update-icon-cache`, I am wondering if there is another solution that:

a) Does not require an svg, but works with png files
 b) Does not require that I write into `/usr`

Comment: It should be possible... [see the answers here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207513)

Comment: Thank you very much for this link. Looks like its exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [different icons for generic source-code and other files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207513/different-icons-for-generic-source-code-and-other-files)